# How can I separate divs in snake body ( Snake JS game)

Tags: javascript

Found a problem writing JS game ( Snake ). Can't separating divs in snake body. Now I achieved that several part of snake body move in one direction, but one on another ( top an left position update the same for each block ). I want to separate them like in a snake, but don't have idea how to do that. Can somebody to give some advices?
Here is my js code ( works only in chrome ):

```
// field object
 var fieldObj = {
    field: document.getElementById( "field" ),
    w: 480,
    h: 580
 },
// snake object
snakeObj = {
    snakeBody: document.getElementsByClassName( "snake-body" ),
    p: {
       x: 0, // position x 
       y: 0  // position y
    },
    v: {
       x: 1, // velocity( here you can change speed)
       y: 1
 },
 keys: {
    up: null,
    l: null,
    r: null,
    down: null
  },
  update: function() {
     // this.snake.style.top = this.p.x + "px";
     // this.snake.style.left = this.p.y + "px";

    if ( this.keys.down ) {
        this.p.x += this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.up ) {
        this.p.x -= this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.r ) {
        this.p.y += this.v.y;
    }else if ( this.keys.l ) {
        this.p.y -= this.v.y;
    }
    for (var i = this.snakeBody.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       this.snakeBody[i].style.top = this.p.x + "px";
       this.snakeBody[i].style.left = this.p.y + "px";
    }
   }
 },
 // game object 
 gameObj = {
    getRandom: function( num ) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * num );
    },
    createSnakeTarget: function() {
       var snakeTarget = document.createElement( "div" );
           snakeTarget.className = "snake-target";
           snakeTarget.style.top = this.getRandom( fieldObj.h ) + "px";
           snakeTarget.style.left = this.getRandom( fieldObj.w ) + "px";

          fieldObj.field.appendChild( snakeTarget );
    },
   stopGame: function() {
       var stopMessage = document.createElement("div");
           stopMessage.className = "stop-message";
           stopMessage.style.background = "white";

          fieldObj.field.appendChild( stopMessage );
          //TODO: write message to stopGame
   }
 };

  gameObj.createSnakeTarget();
 //gameObj.stopGame();

  // Crome works only with keydown and keyup
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  // before changing direction you have to put previous direction to false
   if ( event.keyCode == 38 ) {
        snakeObj.keys.up = true;
        snakeObj.keys.down = false;
   } else if ( event.keyCode == 40 ) {
        snakeObj.keys.down = true;
        snakeObj.keys.up = false;
   } else if ( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
       snakeObj.keys.r = true;
       snakeObj.keys.up = false;
       snakeObj.keys.down = false;
   } else if ( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
       snakeObj.keys.l = true;
       snakeObj.keys.r = false;
       snakeObj.keys.up = false;
       snakeObj.keys.down = false;
   }
  }, false);
//TODO: add event hendler to click to some button
 window.addEventListener( "load", function gameLoop() {
    snakeObj.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
  }, false);
```

Here is codepen http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/esFbf 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried all possible keys, but the snake didn't move. Is it actually working atm?

Comment: It works, press any arrow key. Maybe you first need to click on field, window recived focus and then press arrow key

Comment: It just gives `ReferenceError: event is not defined` in firebug.

Comment: Do you have code that adds new divs to the body? What you could do is add divs to your body and only animate the first div. When you move you set each div in the position the previous div was in before you moved it. Does that make sense?

Comment: try here, please http://jsbin.com/utezaq/2 and it works in chrome, maybe you tried in firefox?

Comment: @putvande Don't have yet, want to try how to make it works if I write several divs in html

Comment: @putvande  Yes it make sense. Trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be of help to you how you can seperate the divs in your snake.

(I have used jQuery by the way)

What I have done is add a `div` for each body peace and give them the same `width`, `height`, `position` etc.

And then I have my movement function that gets called with a setInterval of 1 second.
It loops trough all the `div` I have as a body.
`if($(this).index() == 0){` is only for the first body block. All the others follow where the first block has been.

`xdir` and `ydir` get updated when you click one of the arrow keys.

```
    var speed = 10;
    var xdir = 0;
    var ydir = 1;

function handle_movement(){

    // Loop trough body divs
    $('div.body').each(function(){
        // Get x and y position
        var x = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
        var y = parseInt($(this).css('top'));

        // Only move the first div in the right direction
        if($(this).index() == 0){
            $(this).css({'left': x + (xdir * speed) + 'px','top': y + (ydir * speed) + 'px'});
        } else {
            // All other divs follow their previous sibling
            var prevleft = $(this).prev('.body').data('left');
            var prevtop = $(this).prev('.body').data('top');
            $(this).css({'left':prevleft, 'top':prevtop});
        }
        // Keep track of where the body has gone
        $(this).data({'left':x, 'top':y}).show();
    });
}
```

Hope it makes sense.

See my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mLaA/).